# Optional parameters in report

Tags: crystal-reports

```
{DateView.Id}={?Id}
{DateView.Date}={?Date}
```

I use this code in the Record Selection formula with no errors. If I enter the value of either `Id` or `Date`, this alert message shows:

> Please enter the value

How can I resolve this such that I can do the following?

```
(Not HasValue ({?Id}) Or {DateView.Id} = {?Id})
And
(Not HasValue ({?Date}) Or {DateView.Date} = {?Date})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the parameter to be optional in the Field Explorer. Afterwards, if you still receive the prompt, use the following formula:

```
(IF Hasvalue({?Id}) THEN {DateView.Id} = {?Id} ELSE True)
AND
(IF Hasvalue({?Date}) THEN {DateView.Date} = {?Date} ELSE True)
```

Comment: Thank you 4444. After configuring the parameter to be optional in Field Explorer,It works fine.